# Populating Fields Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Can I populate a text field in a repeating section using the data entered in a different section of the form?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with Cognito Forms. Unfortunately, you can only access the fields within the same container. Therefore, only the fields that are contained in the same section or repeating section are accessible. At this time, the only other option is to use a content field to provide that visual separation/grouping. However, we have discussed providing support for this in a future release.